# align plots groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

I am trying to align the axis of 3 plots that are organized as the following: two on the first row and one on the second row. I would like the axis of the third plot to be aligned with the axis of the plots of the first row. What is the best practice to do so?

[image]

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size= 2 by 1, horizontal sep=0.12\textwidth, vertical     sep=0.0\textwidth,}]
    
    \nextgroupplot[
    scale only axis=true,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    width=0.38\columnwidth,
    height=0.253125\columnwidth,]
    \addplot {rnd};
                
    \nextgroupplot[
    scale only axis=true,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    width=0.38\columnwidth,
    height=0.253125\columnwidth,]
    \addplot {rnd};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis=true,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    width=0.80\columnwidth,
    height=0.253125\columnwidth,]
    \addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want aligned? As you write it now, it is confusing/contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want the left/right edges of the bottom axis to align with the outer edges of the two axes on the top?

First of all, that obviously means the bottom axis has to be as wide as the two top axes combined plus the space between them. You're using `scale only axis` everywhere, and you've specified all lengths explicitly for the first two, so it's a simple calculation. You can even have `pgf` do the calculation for you, with `width=2*0.38\columnwidth+0.12\textwidth`.

In addition, you have to make sure the horizontal alignment is correct. If the ticklabels/ylabels have different widths in the first and third axis, you might get wrong alignment if they're in separate `tikzpicture`s. What I would do is place everything in the same `tikzpicture`, and place the third axis relative the first. There are several ways to do that, below I took what might be the laziest option, and added a negative `yshift` to the big axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}


\begin{groupplot}[
   group style={
      group size= 2 by 1,
      horizontal sep=0.12\textwidth,
      vertical sep=0.0\textwidth,
      group name=toprow
      }]
    
    \nextgroupplot[
    scale only axis=true,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    width=0.38\columnwidth,
    height=0.253125\columnwidth,]
    \addplot {rnd};
                
    \nextgroupplot[
    scale only axis=true,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    width=0.38\columnwidth,
    height=0.253125\columnwidth,]
    \addplot {rnd};
    \end{groupplot}
% put all plots in same tikzpicture
\begin{axis}[
    yshift=-0.35\columnwidth, % <-- added
    scale only axis=true,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    width=0.76\columnwidth+0.12\textwidth,  % modified 
    height=0.253125\columnwidth
    ]
    \addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```